# PS2 / SMBus communication

Tags: hardware, ps2, smbus

I have an OEM touchpad I want to connect to a PC. The drivers for this touchpad are widely available. I asked the manufacturer for the original datasheet, and it says there, that the touchpad interface/protocol is *PS2/SMBus*.

On the device there is an 8 pin connector - of which 7 pins are used. They are laid out as follows:
[image: Pin assignment]

I do know however that a PS/2 connector has only 6 pins (7 incl. the shield, but is it used at all?), and not 8. I can't see how this connector is compatible with PS/2.

FWIW, this is what the spec had to say about interface:

> ## Interface
>
> #### PS2
>
> Refer to IBM PS2 specification. Internal pull-up resistors (5k
>   typical) are provided on DATA and CLOCK lines.
>
> All the commands specified by IBM are implemented, except for the
>   following:
>
> - "Scaling" and "Set Resolution" commands generate an "ACK" response from the touchpad, but leave the touchpad resolution unchanged.
>
> #### SMBus
>
> Refer to the System Management Bus (SMBus) Specification. Version 2.0.

That's it.

So am I looking here at something that is technically possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TouchPad is a modular embedded device that offers multiple protocols output. You can either wire the ps/2 pins internally or externally with a ps/2 cable, or wire the SMBUS pins (mainly internal only in practice). If the TouchPad is really nice, it might support both interfaces at the same time,  since no pins share functions or overlap.

All pins are broken out to a single 8 pin connector so an OEM laptop builder can wire it as they want. Manufacturer convenience, nothing more.

Newer TouchPad also come with usb interfaces instead of ps/2. Those can be wired to a usb cable the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Only four of the six PS/2 pins are used in a real mouse - clock, data and power/gnd. Clock and data are open collector, hence the pullups.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) :

[image: PS2 Mouse]

There is a useful [description of the PS/2 mouse protocol here](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2mouse/), which I've waded through myself to get a PS/2 mouse talking to a mid-range PIC.

Comment: That matches the first 4 pins of the touchpad, but what about pins 5-7 (SMbus)?

Comment: @pilau I'm assuming that it's *either* PS/2 *or* SMBus, not both.

Comment: What do you mean? From what I gather, it says the interface is PS/2 (physical layer) and the protocol is SMBus (logical layer) - or am I mistaken here?

Comment: @pilau I can't imagine how you'd need both. The PS/2 protocol already has everything you'd expect. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No, but I worry of burning the touchpad if I connect something the wrong way.

Comment: @pilau The only thing you have to fear is fear itself ;-)

Comment: Lol. True dat. But are my concerns justified?

Comment: Both the ps/2 and SMBUS (I2C) are open drain buses. There isn't any concern with burning the device as long as you use the right resistors (5k is fine, and implement open drain on your end.

Comment: The "reserved for" language with the SMBus suggests those pins might not even be functional.

Comment: @gbarry i think it has to do more that smbus is a shared bus, unlike ps/2 which is dedicated.